# How to send sms to 4 to 5 digit number?

Tags: android, sms

In one of my application I need to send SMS to number like 3#### and 4######.

For that I have write code like this but I am not getting sms

```
try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("4######", null, "SMS DATA", null,
                            null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I am not able to find the problem.

Comment: actually this sms number will able to work only for specific country only. so i am not able to run this. bt cient said sms not getting

Comment: That means it is not showing any error toast when the above code gets execute, Am I correct ?

Comment: My guess is that this bug has nothing to do with the fact that the number is short. What phone does your client have? What version of Android? What about you? What real phone do you test on? What version does it have? And yes, you will have to test your app with a different sms number, but again, I don't think that matters.

Comment: i have tested on real number(10 digit) that works